# Clean way extract path parameters from Camel HTTP endpoints

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

Ideally I would like to have a route like this:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/{pathParam1}/{pathParam2)
```

So that a consumer would then be able to access the value using:

```
exchange.getIn().getHeader("pathParam1")
```

The camel [rest component](http://camel.apache.org/rest.html) supports this but I would then need to repeat the route for each request method (GET, PUT, etc.) and I am not sure if using the rest component adds overhead that I don't need.

I see that camel does automatically parse out query parameters into exchange headers, but I can only find the full path and want to avoid my own parsing.

Comment: Yeah this is not supported. However if the rest idiom of {name} is becoming more natural we could look into adding that as general to the HTTP components. Maybe with an option on the component to turn this off/on, in case some weird use-case where the path really includes { }

Comment: For now you can write your own util method that takes the full context path and parses it, you can split it based on / and then grab the desired element

Comment: Thanks for confirming @claus-ibsen, I think it would be great to add this feature as it seems a nice way of having named path params rather than just numeric index based (i.e. if I were to spilt on /)

Comment: Is there any new solution for this? @ClausIbsen Still do we need to parse it ourselves?